# Django-graphene: how to filter with an OR operator

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I am pretty new with both Django and Graphene, and couldn't get around a problem which might be fairly simple, but I had no luck with the docs or google to get an answer.

Let's say I have the following model:

```
class Law(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    description = TextField(default=None)
    body = models.TextField(default=None)
```

And the following schema:

```
class LawType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Law
        filter_fields = {
            "year": ["exact"],
            "number": ["exact"],
            "description": ["contains"],
            "body": ["icontains"],
        }
        interfaces = (graphene.Node, )

class Query(graphene.AbstractType):
    all_laws = DjangoFilterConnectionField(LawType)

    def resolve_all_laws(self, args, context, info):
        return models.Law.objects.all()
```

How do I make a query or define a FilterSet class so that it will return a list of objects such that a word is found in the description **or** in the body?

```
{
    allLaws(description_Icontains: "criminal", body_Icontains: "criminal") {
        edges{
            node{
                year
                number
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't find an answer in the [graphene-django documentation](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/filtering/#) nor in the [django-filter documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Any clues? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the base Django framework by using a `Q` object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

For instance, this statement would yield a single Q object representing the `OR` of the two queries:

```
Q(description__icontains='criminal') | Q(body__icontains='criminal')
```

You can pass this statement into a `filter` query:

```
Law.objects.filter(
    Q(description__icontains='criminal') | Q(body__icontains='criminal')
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at the docs, and I think I get how the Q objects work, but I can't figure out how to implement it in my code and make it work with graphene...

Comment: I've not used Graphene before, but looking at this page: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/master/examples/cookbook-plain/cookbook/recipes/schema.py I imagine you could define a field in your query whose resolve method uses a Q lookup like this.

Comment: I found a specific solution here: https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql/blob/master/content/backend/graphql-python/7-filtering.md and tweaked it to match my needs. It was with Q objects indeed. Thanks.